# I know the temperature and air pressure at specific height, can I estimate the temperature at different height?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, temperature, weather, meteorology

I know what the temperature is at a specific height, and I know the air pressure there.
Is it possible to estimate the temperature at a different height?

(It's a public weather station, it has an API, and I'm attempting to guesstimate the temperature at my house :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The temperature drop in the atmosphere (more precisely the troposphere) is approx 10 K per km (when assuming a dry atmosphere, and about 7 K for the average atmosphere, see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lapse_rate), which is known as the lapse rate. However, in the stratosphere the temperature will rise again as a function of UV absorption at ozone.

Comment: Thank you! :) Exactly what I was looking for.